# Css animation to put a color layer over a background image while hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to achieve the effect shown here: 
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

Where the color changes when the user hovers over the element. But I want this to occur overtop a background image I set and for the animation to reverse when the user moves their cursor away from the element.

An example of which can be found here: 
http://thefoxwp.com/portfolio-packery-4-columns/

I can get the transition part working with:

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: blue;
  <!--background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/380/222/nature");-->
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
}

.box:hover {
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

But I am having trouble achieving it with a background image and making the white animation transparent over top of it.

Comment: Take a look.Here is the demo https://jsfiddle.net/uuv2p02h/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way to do it would be to use an overlay over the image and apply `transition` on its `opacity`.

See this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/q0d2rqt0/)

Use a wrapper `div` for both `.box` and `.overlay`. Since we want overlay to placed exactly top of the box, we absolute positioned `overlay` on the top of `box`.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="overlay">
  </div>
</div>
```

You Css

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;  
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  //background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/380/222/nature");
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-out;
}

.overlay:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Comment: This is the closest to what I am after, but is there a way for the background image to fade back in like in the example I posted in the OP?

Comment: @Pipeline `background-image` property is not animatable. See **[This](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties)**. Therefore you cannot apply any `transition` on it. Besides you are mixing `background-color` and `background-image` property, you can only see one of them at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `background-image:none` on `.box:hover`. It will remove the `background-image` and you can get the `background-color` work. As soon as, you move out of the `div.box`, image will appear again.

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;

 background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/380/222/nature");
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
}

.box:hover {
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that background and background-image cannot both exist at the same time.  try using nested div tags: one with the background color nested inside the background-image.